# Extract certain amount of factor levels in R

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

I have a data frame with a column with more than 100 factor levels.

I want to extract rows to make the column just have 50 factor levels, to decrease the calculation time.

How to randomly extract certain amount of factor levels?

Comment: `sample(levels(MyFactor), 50`

Comment: @G5W Thanks for comment! Yes I can extract factor levels now. Then how to extract rows with those extracted factor levels?

Comment: `ReducedFactors = sample(levels(df$MyFactor), 50);`   `df[which(df$MyFactor %in% ReducedFactors ), ]`

Comment: `smaller.df <- df[MyFactor %in% sample(levels(MyFactor), 50),]`

Comment: @G5W Thanks a lot!

Comment: @amatsuo_net Thanks for comment!

Answer (score 2):

To avoid no answer ...

You can use `sample` to get a random sample of the factor and then use `%in%` to select the relevant rows of your data.frame.

```
ReducedFactors = sample(levels(df$MyFactor), 50) 
df[which(df$MyFactor %in% ReducedFactors ), ]
```